# Lex confidence score is not accurate

Tags: amazon-lex

I have a Lex bot with one intent (PolicyIntent), and one training phrase.  The training phrase is "What is the policy system status?"

No matter what I type such as "What time is it?" Lex matches to this intent with confidence scores as high as 0.8 -- the phrase is completely different.

Has anyone worked with this type of problem before?  What did you do?  Find some way to correct the confidence score (anything less than 1.0 should be subtracted by 20%?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you still need an answer on this, but having only one training phrase has meant your model doesn't have much to base the matching on. To you as a human the phrase is semantically completely different, but to the model those are actually similar phrases since it has only one example it doesn't know what are the "important" parts of the phrase from your perspective.
You can learn a bit more here about how to create good training data https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/best-practices-for-creating-amazon-lex-interaction-models/